Why is the loss function ordinate of llama2 paper ppl?
The ordinate of llama2's loss function is ppl. Does this mean that llama2 uses ppl as the loss function?
Unfortunately, I can't find a way to calculate the llama2 loss function on the Internet.
And in llama's paper, the corresponding position is loss. Does this mean that the llama2 model's loss function is calculated in the same way as ppl?
